# как сделать устойчивые и неустойчивые алгоритмы упорядочения

Tags: c++

один устойчивый и один неустойчивый.
Информацию о Т путешественников содержит следующие поля: код билета (целое число), фамилия пассажира, информация о багаже - количество вещей и общий вес.
Ключи: а) код билета, б) вес багажа. Т = 10.
в результате программа должна работать по схеме :,
ввода информации (читается с файла);
вывода данных в порядке создания;
запрос, в каком порядке хотим их видеть, например,
0 - в предварительном порядке; 1 - упорядоченных по фамилии, 2 - упорядоченных по году рождения, 3 - по рейтингу.

```
#include<iostream>
    #include<Windows.h>
    #include<fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include<cstring>
    using namespace std;
    struct Travelers
    {
        int ticket_code;
        char surname_traveler[20];
        char luggage_weight[15];
        int numberofthings;
    };
    
    
    bool ReadFile(Travelers*& arr_Travelers, int& size)
    {
        arr_Travelers = new Travelers[100];
        size = 0;
    
        ifstream fin("Travelers.txt");
        while (fin >> arr_Travelers[size].surname_traveler)
        {
            fin >> arr_Travelers[size].ticket_code;
            fin >> arr_Travelers[size].surname_traveler;
            fin >> arr_Travelers[size].luggage_weight;
            fin >> arr_Travelers[size].numberofthings;
    
            ++size;
            if (size >= 100)
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    void print(Travelers* arr_Travelers, int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << arr_Travelers[i].ticket_code << endl;
            cout << arr_Travelers[i].surname_traveler << endl;
            cout << arr_Travelers[i].luggage_weight << endl;
            cout << arr_Travelers[i].numberofthings << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    int main()
    {
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
    
        bool ReadFile(Travelers * &arr_Travelers, int& size);
        void print(Travelers * arr_Travelers, int size);
    
        int size;
        Travelers* arr_Travelers;
        if (ReadFile(arr_Travelers, size))
            print(arr_Travelers, size);
        else
            cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
    
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Реализуйте. Например, mergesort -- устойчивая, а тривиальная реализаия quicksort будет неустойчивой.

Comment: Я бы сказал что любая реализация qiucksort будет неустойчивой. И примерно половина реализаций mergesort окажутся устойчивыми. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, гугл не согласен с вами -- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stable-quicksort/

Comment: Тот пример quicksort использует дополнительную линейную память, что делает его не совсем настоящим быстрым quicksort (настоящий работает без дополнительных буферов).